# Can I pass in a parameter from an application to a Cascading Parameter - Crystal Reports?

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report

```
We have an application that passes in a parameter to our reports so they pop up automatically based on the pass in. This works great for all the reports that have a static parameter.
```

I have a new report that uses a cascading parameter. The first parameter in the cascade needs to be passed in and all the others need to be limited to it. Right now, the cascading parameter ignores the pass in and makes the user enter the information.

Can a pass in be used on a cascading paramter?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you passing in the first cascading parameter?

Comment: I am passing it in through an application. An admin logs in to the application and a school is appended with the session data. When the report opens "@school" parameter has a value which passes into the report with a "@school" parameter there. With the other repots this works great. The cascading parameter fails to recognize it though. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there no way to do this?